# Exclude in between dates

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 dates `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`, I have a table in which I have stored shift dates of specific employees structure is defined below like this.

```
EmpCode   ShiftCode  StartDate    EndDate
1         24         2019-10-01   2019-10-12
1         26         2019-10-13   2019-10-20
```

If I provide `@startDate` = `'2019-10-01'` and `@endDate` = `'2019-10-15'`
It should not get the following data, I want to exclude the rows where dates are in between the provided dates.

If the parameters provided are lets say are `'2019-10-21'` and `'2019-10-31'` respectively then it's should give me the employee code as its shift is not defined in these dates and I can add it.

This is what I have tried so far but it's not returning the desired result.

```
SELECT 
    EmpCode 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    [Roster].[EndDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate OR 
    [Roster].[EndDate] NOT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Comment: Please provide the following info: what data type are the StartDate and EndDate columns? What is the result you get with your query?

Comment: @MichaelTobisch dates are `datetime` and I am getting `EmpCode 1` which shouldn't be returned because it's shift already exists in provided dates

Comment: Your code is not going to work in the example you have given, You are searching for an end date between `'2019-10-01'` and `'2019-10-15'` so you will always get the second row back as the end date is not in this date range?

Answer (score 2):

As Shikar has deleted his post, the simple solution would be...

```
...
WHERE
    @startDate NOT BETWEEN [Roster].[StartDate] AND [Roster].[EndDate] AND 
    @endDate NOT BETWEEN [Roster].[StartDate] AND [Roster].[EndDate]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing the 'NOT's position. Also you did have a copy paste error on your where clause.

```
SELECT 
    EmpCode 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
   NOT (
       [Roster].[StartDate] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND 
       [Roster].[EndDate] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
   )
```